# Code changes not reflected in output

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyc

I'm having some issues with updating my code. I can run my code and it works fine. But when I make adjustments to the code the output stays the same as when I originally ran the file. If I create a new .py file and just copy and paste the updated code it produces the desired output with the updates. Why is my original file not reflecting the changes in the output?

My specific example is in the code below. The code ran and produced outputs as expected. Then I updated it to add the "sector" and "close" variables. However, the new output did not include the data, just the names in the header. Does it have to do with the .pyc file?

```
import multiprocessing
import datetime
import re
from progressbar import ProgressBar
import csv
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

def mp_worker(s):
    url1 = ("https://research.tdameritrade.com/grid/public/research/stocks/fundamentals?symbol=" + s)
    url2 = ("https://research.tdameritrade.com/grid/public/research/stocks/summary?symbol=" + s)
    url3 = ("https://research.tdameritrade.com/grid/public/research/stocks/industryposition?symbol=" + s)
    htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
    try:
        response3 = urllib2.urlopen(url3)
        tree3 = etree.parse(response3, htmlparser)
        perf = tree3.xpath("""//*[@id="stock-industrypositionmodule"]/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/text()""")

        if len(perf) > 0:
            EPS5yr = tree3.xpath("""//*[@id="stock-industrypositionmodule"]/div/div/table/tbody[2]/tr[4]/td[1]/text()""")
        else:
            response1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1)
            tree1 = etree.parse(response1, htmlparser)
            EPS5yr = tree1.xpath("""//*[@id="layout-full"]/div[3]/div/div[3]/section/div/div/div[1]/div/dl/dd[1]/div/label/span/text()""")

        response2 = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
        tree2 = etree.parse(response2, htmlparser)
        EPSttm = tree2.xpath("""//*[@id="stock-summarymodule"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/dl/ul/li[3]/dd/text()""")
        sector = tree2.xpath("""//*[@id="layout-header"]/div[1]/div/text()""")
        indy = tree2.xpath("""//*[@id="layout-header"]/div[1]/div/a[1]/text()""")
        close = tree2.xpath("""//*[@id="stock-quotebar"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/dl/dd/text()""")

    except Exception as e:
        EPS5yr = 'Error'
        EPSttm = 'Error'
        perf = 'Error'
        indy = 'Error'
        close = 'Error'
        sector = 'Error'
        pass

    return s, close, EPS5yr, EPSttm, perf, sector, indy

def mp_handler():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
    file = ('total_market' + '_' + date +'.csv')
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(16)
    symbols = {'AABA',
    'AAOI',
    'AAPL',
    'AAWC'}
    with open(file, "ab") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['Symbol','Price','5 Yr EPS','EPS TTM','52 Wk Perf','Sector','Industry'])
        for result in p.imap(mp_worker, symbols):
            # (filename, count) tuples from worker
            writer.writerow(result)

if __name__=='__main__':
    mp_handler()
```

Comment: It's unlikely to be the .pyc file unless you've done something very weird—but if you want to make sure, it's very easy to test. Just delete the .pyc file (or even the whole `__pycache__` subdirectory) and see what happens.

Comment: Meanwhile, the first thing I'd check (based on the kinds of silly mistakes _i_ make) is whether you're actually (a) saving the file in your editor, and (b) editing the same file you're running as opposed to a copy of the file in a different directory (or even on a different computer, if you regularly ssh into a separate dev box).

Comment: I tried those things already with no luck. moved the .pyc file out of the directory, used the "-B" option, and ensured I was running the file I was actually editing.

Comment: Well, I did say it was unlikely, but now we know for sure that’s not it, which is progress.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question I'd like to provide another possible solution. If the module is something you installed (e.g you have a setup.py file and you've pip installed your project) then uninstalling the module could fix it. This turned out to solve my problem when I ran into it.